# Static Friction

Tags: mathematical-physics

27. The coefficient of static friction between car’s tires and a level road is 0.80. If the car is to be stopped in a maximum time of 3.0 s, its maximum speed is
    (a) 2.4 m/s             (b) 23.5 m/s          (c) 7.8 m/s              (d) 2.6 m/s

Perhaps an easy question for some, but I simply do not understand how to apply the formula for static equilibrium in this case without being given any mass or force.

Please help out!

Comment: Call the mass $M$. Do the calculation with $M$. Discover that $M$ cancels out, so it doesn't matter what its value is.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I think I've solved the problem, but I'm a little confused...isn't the coefficient of *kinetic* friction important for this problem? Presumably the car is sliding to a stop from an initial speed $v_0$?

Comment: Kinetic friction would be important if the car were skidding to a stop.  In this case it sounds like the car is slowing down as quickly as possible without skidding.

Comment: So a car that is slowing down because neither the brake or accelerator are being pressed is slowed down by static friction?

Comment: @SplitInfinity, in that case, there are other frictions, e.g., in the wheels rotating and the axels and from air drag.

Comment: @SplitInfinity - It doesn't matter if the brake or accelerator is being pressed. That is internal to the system of the car. What matters is the interaction of the car with what is external to it, which is the road. And rolling tires have static friction because the tire contact does not move with respect to the road.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
  ma &= -\mu mg \\
  a &= -\mu g \\
  \frac{v-u}{t} &= -\mu g \\
  \frac{0-u}{3} &= -0.8 \times 9.8 \\
  u &= 23.5
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you so very much! A very thorough explanation! :)

Answer (score 1):

If $M$ is the mass of the car, the frictional force is $\mu M g$, where $\mu$ is the coefficient of friction. This is the only force in horizontal direction. Therefore, if $a$ is the acceleration then $Ma = \mu M g$ or $a = \mu g$. If $u$ is the initial velocity and $v$ is the velocity after time $t$ then $v = u + at$. Since the car stops after $t = 3.0$ seconds, $v = 0$ at that time. Therefore the maximum $u$ is $|at| = |\mu g t|$. Plugging in the values gives $u = 23.52$ meters per second.

Answer (score 1):

The acceleration will be given by 
$$
\frac{F_f}{m} = a = \frac{v_f -v_i}{\Delta t}
$$
or since $\mu =\frac{F_f}{F_n}$
$$
\frac{\mu F_n}{m} = \frac{v_f-v_i}{\Delta t}
$$
then
$$
\mu g = \frac{v_f-v_i}{\Delta t} 
$$
or 
$$
v_i = - \mu g \Delta t
$$